using python get the reserved instance remainging capacity
can I get the reserved instance's remaining capacity using Python code?
by the AWS console, I can't see which on-demand instances are used for reserved instances, and how many on-demand instances are reserved.

can I create multiple reserved instances with the same instance type and platform?

how can I get how many on-demand instances are attached to the particular reserved instance? example: I created 2 reserved instances with t2.medium and Linux/Unix, with an instance count is 5, then I created 4 on-demand instances with the same config, now how can I get which on-demand instance is attached to which reserved instance?

after attaching the on-demand instance to the reserved instance, how can I get the remaining capacity in a reserved instance?

can I get the above details using Python code? yes or no.


please provide answers to each question separately.
can I get the reserved instance's remaining capacity using Python code?
